# BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

**Data from source system** -

> abc@abc.com # kafka-avro-console-consumer --bootstrap-server
>   localhost:9092 --topic TTDF.TCDCPOC_DATA_TYPES --from-beginning
>   --property print.key=true --property print.value=true --property key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

```
"57508564"      {"data":{"SEQNO":{"int":57508564},"TEXT":{"string":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,"},"BIGNUM":{"long":11122233344447},"BINOBJ":{"bytes":"#~Â¦`Â¬| DATA IS STORED AS BINARY|>"},"CHAROBJ":{"string":"<text>THIS DATA IS STORED AS CLOB</text>"},"FLOATNUM":{"double":6.62607015E-34},"CHARVAR":{"string":"consectetur adipiscing elit,sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."}},"headers":{"operation":"REFRESH","changeSequence":"","timestamp":"","streamPosition":"","transactionId":"","changeMask":null,"columnMask":null}}
```

^CProcessed a total of 6 messages

**Schema registry** -

```
{
  "subject": "TTDF.TCDCPOC_DATA_TYPES-value",
  "version": 3,
  "id": 12,
  "schema": "{"type":"record","name":"DataRecord","fields":[{"name":"data","type":{"type":"record","name":"Data","fields":[{"name":"SEQNO","type":["null","int"],"default":null},{"name":"TEXT","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"BIGNUM","type":["null","long"],"default":null},{"name":"BINOBJ","type":["null","bytes"],"default":null},{"name":"CHAROBJ","type":["null","string"],"default":null},{"name":"FLOATNUM","type":["null","double"],"default":null},{"name":"CHARVAR","type":["null","string"],"default":null}]}},{"name":"headers","type":{"type":"record","name":"Headers","fields":[{"name":"operation","type":{"type":"enum","name":"operation","symbols":["INSERT","UPDATE","DELETE","REFRESH"]}},{"name":"changeSequence","type":"string"},{"name":"timestamp","type":"string"},{"name":"streamPosition","type":"string"},{"name":"transactionId","type":"string"},{"name":"changeMask","type":["null","bytes"]},{"name":"columnMask","type":["null","bytes"]}]}}]}"
}
```

**Errors** -

```
[2019-02-12 12:28:48,364] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=mongo-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted. (org.apache
.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask:584)
org.bson.BsonInvalidOperationException: readStartDocument can only be called when CurrentBSONType is DOCUMENT, not when CurrentBSONType is STRING.
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.verifyBSONType(AbstractBsonReader.java:690)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.checkPreconditions(AbstractBsonReader.java:722)
        at org.bson.AbstractBsonReader.readStartDocument(AbstractBsonReader.java:450)
        at org.bson.codecs.BsonDocumentCodec.decode(BsonDocumentCodec.java:81)
        at org.bson.BsonDocument.parse(BsonDocument.java:62)
        at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.converter.JsonRawStringRecordConverter.convert(JsonRawStringRecordConverter.java:32)
        at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.converter.SinkConverter.convert(SinkConverter.java:44)
        at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkTask.lambda$buildWriteModel$3(MongoDbSinkTask.java:186)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkTask.buildWriteModel(MongoDbSinkTask.java:185)
        at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkTask.processSinkRecords(MongoDbSinkTask.java:122)
        at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkTask.lambda$null$0(MongoDbSinkTask.java:111)
        at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
        at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkTask.lambda$put$1(MongoDbSinkTask.java:110)
        at java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1289)
        at at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkTask.put(MongoDbSinkTask.java:109)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:564)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:175)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:219)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2019-02-12 12:28:48,364] ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=mongo-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:177)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Exiting WorkerSinkTask due to unrecoverable exception.
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.deliverMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:586)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:322)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:225)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:193)
```

**Config file** -

```
{
   "name": "mongo",
   "config": {

        "key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "internal.key.converter":"org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter",
        "internal.key.converter.schemas.enable":"false",
        "key.converter.schemas.enable": false,
        "key.ignore":"true",

        "value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "internal.value.converter":"io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
        "value.converter.schemas.enable": true,
        "internal.value.converter.schemas.enable":"true",

        "key.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",
        "value.converter.schema.registry.url":"http://localhost:8081",


        "connector.class": "at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkConnector",
        "topics":"TTDF.TCDCPOC_DATA_TYPES",
        "mongodb.connection.uri":"mongodb://xxxx:Password1@xxxx:27017/testdb?authSource=xxx",
        "mongodb.collection":"TCDCPOC_DATA_TYPES",

        "_comment":"transforms\":\"createKey",
        "_comment":"transforms.createKey.type:org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Flatten$Value",
        "_comment":"transforms.Flatten.delimiter:_",
        "_comment":"transforms.createKey.type:io.confluent.connect.transforms.Drop$Key",
        "_comment":"transforms.createKey.skip.missing.or.null\":\"true",
        "_comment":"transforms.createKey.type\":\"org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey",
        "_comment":"transforms.createKey.fields\":\"data.SEQNO",
        "_comment":"transforms.createKey.static.key:test"
        }
}
```